# Java Eclipse java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError JNI loading dll and C code

Tags: java, c, eclipse, dll

I am trying to use a code library that involves using JNI to access dll files and C code. I have tried everything I can think of and I can't seem to resolve this error.

The problem is with

```
 System.loadLibrary("psjw");
```

where psjw is a dll/C code that is located in the same folder as the java class invoking this method. I have tried

- setting `java.library.path` in the JVM differently in Eclipse
- putting the file in a separate folder and adding this as a Native Library in Eclipse
- using `System.load("fully qualified path in here");` instead

none of which resolve the issue.

I'm using a mac with OSX 10.8.5 but I don't think that's relevant.

Comment: What does the exception's message say?

Answer (score 1):

You can't load a `dll` file on Mac OS X. OS X JNI code is in `jnilib` files and have to be built for OS X not Windows.